# Android Support Library in 1 Project and 2 libaries

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have my project and two libraries jfeinstein10 / SlidingMenu and JakeWharton / Android-ViewPagerIndicator and have problem with android support libary. I'm add both libraries as android code into workspace and I'm used in other project, but in the current project i'm used both libraries and have errors "Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
Found 3 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time." How use this libabries without this problem

Comment: Just right click Android Tools -> Add Support Library on all of them to keep them in sync

Answer (score 1):

In such case you need to use support library in Multi-level fashion.

**your current scenario is like this.**

1. Lib-project-1 (contains android-support jar)
2. Lib-project-2 (contains android-support jar)
3. Your-project (contains android-support jar)

**How you can resolve this?**

1. Remove android-support jar from "Lib-project-2" and "your-project"
2. Add "Lib-project-1 " as Library project in "Lib-project-2"
3. Add "Lib-project-2 " as Library project in "your-project"